# postfix - dns error - can't resolve my A or MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

I've installed postfix on my arch linux pc. I use systemd-resolved and systemd-networkd to establish a network connection.

I want to use postfix as a satellite system to send some mails if my raid systems is broken.

So, when I want to send some test mails with `echo "Body" | mail -s "Header" markus.pesch@my-mail.com` postfix write in my logs, that he can't resolve my domain after a A or MX record

> Okt 21 22:16:54 markus-pc postfix/error[17574]: F1C6E2E0C10: to=, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=360970, delays=360969/0.57/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp1.example.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
>
> Okt 21 22:16:54 markus-pc postfix/error[17569]: 0448E2E0C0E: to=, relay=none, delay=360970, delays=360969/0.57/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp1.example.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
>
> Okt 21 22:16:54 markus-pc postfix/error[17577]: F420B2E0B46: to=, relay=none, delay=360970, delays=360969/0.57/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp1.example.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
>
> Omt 21 22:16:54 markus-pc postfix/error[17572]: F257B2E0C12: to=, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=360970, delays=360969/0.57/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp1.example.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)

But when I tried it with dig, I get a valid response.

How can I fix this dns error, that my local postfix installation can find my mailserver and can send him some mails?

Volker

Comment: At first glance it appears that your system is only trying to do IPv6 lookups, indicated by the  `AAAA` records and the domain may not be configured for those. When you use dig to test  you may get to see IPv4 A records instead, which probably are the default? If it is your own domain, adding  the actual ipv6 records may be a solution.

Comment: Yes, it's my domain and my server has an A, AAAA and MX record. My mailserver runs fine since 2 years. I can't understand why my local postfix installation on my arch linux pc can't lookup the records.

Comment: Have you tried using `traceroute` or `mtr` to verify that you actually have dual stack connectivity to the internet?

Comment: Okay, I tried it with `traceroute` and `mtr`. It's a little bit crazy because with traceroute he want to resolve my valid ipv6 address but he goes to a wrong ipv6 address. The resolved address and the target address are totally different.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed this error. Now it's the right ipv6 address. I such tried to change `internet_protocols` to `ipv4` in postfix' main.cf, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to double check your

> /etc/resolv.conf

and

> /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf

to find any issues about name resolution?

The AAAA record refers to IPV6 addresses, maybe you just ran into a misconfiguration of your DNS/network!

Comment: So, I have this two records in my resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.178.1
nameserver fd00::ca0e:14ff:febf:46c9

I can't find a resolve.conf file under /var/spool/postfix/etc. I don't have the directory /etc/ in /var/spool/postfix. Must I create it and symlink it to the origin resolv.conf?

Comment: @VolkerRaschek When you see an IP address starting with `fd00::` there is 99.99999% chance it was configured by a person who did not know what they were doing. Where did that address come from? It may be that your router is misbehaved or that your ISP is sending it a bad configuration.

Comment: The address with `fd00::` come from systemd-resolved. I've added now manually the ipv6 address from my router in `etc/systemd/resolv.conf`. It start with `2003:a:c7d:`.